# Plotly adds days to x-axis when date column is in POSIXct class

Tags: r, plotly, posixct

I'm trying to plot a time series using Plotly, but it adds days that are not in the original dataset. The dates are in POSIXct class.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(
  Date = as.POSIXct(c('2022-10-20 10:11:29',
                      '2022-10-20 14:11:29',
                      '2022-10-24 16:31:33',
                      '2022-10-24 19:31:33')),
  Names = rep('X', 4),
  Value = seq(1, 4)
  )

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Date, y = ~Value, 
               color = ~Names, type = 'scatter', 
               mode = 'lines', 
               colors = 'blue')
```

[Plotly Output (red shows the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxXGp.png)

As we can see from the image above, even though the days 2022-10-21, 2022-10-22, and 2022-10-23 don't exist in the dataset, they still appear in the plot. I would like to remove these days and connect '2022-10-20 14:11:29' directly to '2022-10-24 16:31:33'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `Date` to a factor via `as.factor` or a string via `as.character` otheriwse plotly will use a discrete time axis with equidistant ticks:

```
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(Date = as.POSIXct(
  c(
    '2022-10-20 10:11:29',
    '2022-10-20 14:11:29',
    '2022-10-24 16:31:33',
    '2022-10-24 19:31:33'
  )
),
Names = rep('X', 4),
Value = seq(1, 4))

fig <- plot_ly(
  data,
  x = ~ as.factor(Date),
  y = ~ Value,
  color = ~ Names,
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'lines',
  colors = 'blue'
)

fig
```